# CGI mapserver with PostGIS layer: pass SQL WHERE clause in URL paramaters

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I use a third-party software to generate a mapfile and serve them on a OpenLayers based interface from a postgis database.

The postgis table, representing the movements of monks in a specific area, has the following structure (geom column trimmed and name starred for data anonymity):

```
 mmid | monk_code |  monk_name   | year |   geom                                            
------+-----------+--------------+------+--------------
    4 | 4910102   | ***          | 2008 | 0102...2E40
    1 | 4910102   | ***          | 2002 | 0102...2E40
    2 | 4910102   | ***          | 2006 | 0102...2E40
    5 | 4910102   | ***          | 2009 | 0102...2F40
    3 | 4910102   | ***          | 2007 | 0102...2E40
    7 | 4910201   | ***          | 2001 | 0102...2E40
    6 | 4910201   | ***          | 2001 | 0102...2E40
   25 | 4910302   | ***          | 2005 | 0102...2E40
   24 | 4910302   | ***          | 2002 | 0102...3040
   26 | 4910303   | ***          | 2006 | 0102...3040
```

The layer part of the mapfile generated by the middleware looks like this:

```
  LAYER
    CONNECTION "PG: dbname=kc_track user=*** password=*** host=localhost port=5432"
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    DATA "movements_search"
    EXTENT -120 -37 144 51.9
    LABELITEM "year"
    METADATA
      "mm_group"        "Group"
      "ows_featureid"   "mmid"
      "gml_featureid"   "mmid"
      "ows_name"        "movements_search"
      "mmDSTN"  "kc_track"
      "ows_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:900913"
      "ows_title"   "movements_search"
      "mmClass" "us"
      "gml_include_items"   "all"
      "gml_types"   "auto"
    END # METADATA
    NAME "movements_search"
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
```

And the PNG is generated through the following URL:

http://mapmint.gaia.net.cias.kyoto-u.ac.jp/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/mapmint/data/maps/search_testSearch2_movements_search.map&LAYERS=movements_search&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=892784.49024685,-780269.18462653,19399106.279851,5809214.1488647&WIDTH=1891&HEIGHT=673

Which gives the following result:
[image: request result]

Here is the output of `mapserv -v`

```
MapServer version 6.0.3 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

I would like to only show the lines respective to a specific monk (e.g. monk_code = '4910102'). Is there a way to include a filter, such a SQL WHERE clause, in the request URL?

I have full access to the database but the mapfile is generated automatically by the middleware. If there is no other solution, I can dive into the middleware source myself and change the code but I would prefer a solution that could use only the request part.

Edit:

The following WFS request returns the correct points:

http://mapmint.gaia.net.cias.kyoto-u.ac.jp/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/mapmint/data/maps/search_testSearch2_movements_search.map&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.0.0&typename=movements_search&filter=%3CFilter%3E%3CPropertyIsLike%20wildcard=%27*%27%20singleChar=%27.%27%20escape=%27!%27%3E%3CPropertyName%3Emonk_code%3C/PropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E*4910201*%3C/Literal%3E%3C/PropertyIsLike%3E%3C/Filter%3E

But the following WMS request with the same filter still returns all the lines:

http://mapmint.gaia.net.cias.kyoto-u.ac.jp/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/mapmint/data/maps/search_testSearch2_movements_search.map&request=GetMap&LAYERS=movements_search&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&typename=movements_search&filter=%3CFilter%3E%3CPropertyIsLike%20wildcard=%27*%27%20singleChar=%27.%27%20escape=%27!%27%3E%3CPropertyName%3Emonk_code%3C/PropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E*4910201*%3C/Literal%3E%3C/PropertyIsLike%3E%3C/Filter%3E&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&WIDTH=1891&HEIGHT=673&BBOX=892784.49024685,-780269.18462653,19399106.279851,5809214.1488647&FORMAT=image%2Fpng

Comment: The WMS GetMap request is very different from the GetFeature WFS request. WMS GetMap does not support filtering, unless the WMS server you are using supports a propietary, non-standard extension.

Comment: Does your client require WMS, or could you use a standard MapServer CGI call via URL instead?

Comment: I can use a standard MapServer CGI call. The client is based on OpenLayers so it's quite flexible.

Comment: Did you try passing an external SLD that only renders the lines you want?  This functionality is certainly supported by MapServer.

Comment: @nmtoken I will not try it as I am not working on this problem anymore (2012 :) ). Nevertheless, I appreciate your effort commenting on this question. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In the mapfile you can use the clause FILTER, "a valid SQL string corresponding to the logic normally following the 'WHERE' keyword in a SQL query" like shown in this example (http://goo.gl/eUn1u):

```
  CONNECTION "user=dbuser dbname=gisdatabase host=bigserver"   
  PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
  # Get the lines from the 'geom' column of the 'roads' table 
  DATA "geom from roads using srid=4326 using unique gid" 
  STATUS ON
  TYPE LINE 
  # Of the lines in the extents, only render the wide highways 
  FILTER "type = 'highway' and numlanes >= 4"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this filter will need to be dynamic, hence me asking if it is possible to do in the URL parameters. I looked into the validation attribute of the mapfile (http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2009-January/059632.html) but it supposes that I need to change the mapfile generation mechanism.

Comment: Then I would try to get the lines you want using the request GetFeature of WFS; MapServer features WFS. One of the things this WFS request allows is filtering features by an attribute, like, for example, an id. This id could be given via an URL parameter.

Comment: Edited question with my current WMS try